# Why, for $\ln(\frac{x_1}{x_2}) = \ln(x_2) - \ln(x_1)$ and not the reverse?

Tags: logarithms

I would've thought, intuitively, it would be $$\ln(\frac{x_1}{x_2}) = \ln(x_1) - \ln(x_2)$$ But it's not. Why is this the case?

Comment: $\ln(x)=\ln(x/1)=\ln(1)-\ln(x)=-\ln(x)$ accoring to what you are saying.

Comment: Oh my, that's a good point.

Comment: What do you mean by "converse" here?

Comment: The reverse arrangement of the terms on the RHS. Leo163 illustrated the implication mathematically above.

Comment: Ah, that is merely the "reverse." Converse has a specific meaning.

Comment: Gah! I'll edit it.

Comment: The thing you thought was right is, in fact, right. Who told you otherwise?

Comment: Take care : $\frac {x_1}{x_2} >0$ does not imply $x_1,x_2 >0$

Comment: Wait, really? I was gonna say, since I was conditioned that way. In an answer for physics lecture notes, the following was obtained: $-NRT [\ln(V_2) - \ln (V_1)] = NRT \ln(\frac{V_1}{V_2})$. I reckon it's fine, since the $RHS$ is $-1$ times the $LHS$, so the fraction must switch?

Comment: There's a missing $|$ in your last comment. Anyway, note that if $0<t<1$ then $|\ln t| = -\ln t$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Right, because it's logarithmic so it starts at $(-\infty, 1)$ and becomes positive. How do I piece that together with switching the terms of the quotient?